# Reuse function call with argument of different possible types in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering if there is a way to reuse the call to the function `template_fun` in the following c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


template <typename T>
double template_fun(T arg)
{
    double a = 1.1;
    a += (double)arg;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    int r = std::rand() % 2;
    double out;

    switch(r)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            int arg = 1;
            out = template_fun(arg);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            double arg = 1.2;
            out = template_fun(arg);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << out << "\n";
}
```

Since the line `out = template_fun(arg);` is repeated, I was hoping there was a way to reuse it somehow. Obviously, this issue of calling a template function with different input data types depending on an input is really what I'm getting at. The code I'm working on is much more complex. I am not particularly hopeful for a clever solution, since it would probably mean defining the data type of `arg` at runtime. But perhaps I am missing something.

Thank you in advance for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful since you say your code is much more complex but you can use `out = (r ? template_fun(1) : template_fun(1.2));`

Comment: _"Since the line out = template_fun(arg); is repeated, I was hoping there was a way to reuse it somehow."_ Can you elaborate about this? Your template function works as intended it seems.

Comment: @NathanOliver as you said, it wouldn't really work in my code. But regardless, as I understand it, that line would require defining `out` as a `double`, which defeats the point of the template anyway.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure! The template function is working fine. I want to know if there is a way I can avoid having multiple function calls, since at the end of the day, it is the same line of code that is being used twice. That would probably imply defining `arg` before this function call in a way in which in can be either a `double` or an `int` depending on the value of `r`.

Comment: You need to have `arg` of N different types and all these types need to be spelled out somewhere, somehow.

Comment: The problem is, that all code dependent on `r` cannot be solved with nice template-metaprogramming techniques due to the fact, that `r` is a random run-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some `variant` class, and do something like:

```
struct template_fun : boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    template <typename T>
    double operator() (T arg) const
    {
        double a = 1.1;
        a += (double)arg;
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    int r = std::rand() % 2;
    boost::variant<int, double> arg;
    double out = 0.0;

    switch(r)
    {
        case 0: { arg = 1;   break; }
        case 1: { arg = 1.2; break; }
    }
    out = boost::apply_visitor(template_fun{}, arg);
    std::cout << out << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4b9d8a6f7282ea9)